# iOS 8 geofencing handle the app opened from lock screen icon

Tags: objective-c, ios8, core-location, cllocationmanager, geofencing

I'm using geofencing in my app by calling this lines of code in needed order and all works good, I can see the icon of my app appears on the lock screen when device enters the tracking region:

```
[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

[self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion: [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(airport.latitude.doubleValue, airport.longitude.doubleValue) radius:AFLLocationManager_geofencingTrackingRegionMetersRadius identifier:airport.code]];
```

and the question is **How do I handle the event when user actually used my app icon on the lock screen and started/resumed the app from the lock screen?**
I believe the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey` in the `launchOptions` dictionary can be used for app launch from lock screen event, but what about app not launching, just becomes active? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there are two events that can trigger and show the app icon on the lock screen [follow link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html)